# Why do my app on heroku restart itself after Sleeping on free dyno Heroku Apps?

Tags: heroku

I have installed [this repo](https://github.com/elasa-Sites/heroku-rapidleech) inside my heroku app as you can see here:

https://ss-leech.herokuapp.com/index.php
 but the problem is restarting and needing to new configuration after any don't using the app for some hours ans after waking up by new request to the site, that is needs to reconfigured again.
here is the last logs after waking up the repo now:

```
Application Logs

2019-11-24T17:15:03.169370+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.51.235.186 - - [24/Nov/2019:17:14:49 +0000] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4919 "https://ss-leech.herokuapp.com/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0

2019-11-24T17:15:03.171180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/index.php" host=ss-leech.herokuapp.com request_id=da926639-82e6-4493-b869-b168edab3560 fwd="198.16.66.139" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13557ms status=200 bytes=5583 protocol=https

2019-11-24T17:20:12.057351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ajax.php?ajax=server_stats" host=ss-leech.herokuapp.com request_id=a2fe19a7-6150-4dab-a204-eb9c30ed9732 fwd="198.16.66.139" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1003ms status=200 bytes=335 protocol=https

2019-11-24T17:20:12.053604+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.206.231 - - [24/Nov/2019:17:20:11 +0000] "GET /ajax.php?ajax=server_stats HTTP/1.1" 200 165 "https://ss-leech.herokuapp.com/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0

2019-11-24T17:20:51.378682+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.221.227 - - [24/Nov/2019:17:20:43 +0000] "GET /files/VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.1-15018445.x86_64.bundle HTTP/1.1" 200 535555604 "-" "-

2019-11-24T17:20:51.523314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/files/VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.1-15018445.x86_64.bundle" host=ss-leech.herokuapp.com request_id=53072973-9ef8-4691-894f-5946ecfe0963 fwd="31.214.231.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7984ms status=200 bytes=535555862 protocol=https

2019-11-24T17:21:14.493640+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.198.238 - - [24/Nov/2019:17:21:06 +0000] "GET /files/VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.1-15018445.x86_64.bundle HTTP/1.1" 206 534162964 "-" "-

2019-11-24T17:21:14.664469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/files/VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.1-15018445.x86_64.bundle" host=ss-leech.herokuapp.com request_id=897fdb3b-e45a-445d-a86c-adcdb1c1e349 fwd="31.214.231.91" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8013ms status=206 bytes=534163285 protocol=https

2019-11-24T17:47:09.038216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ajax.php?ajax=server_stats" host=ss-leech.herokuapp.com request_id=bf5baa23-b7a6-4b4f-8588-6e81c4b64ade fwd="198.16.66.139" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1003ms status=200 bytes=335 protocol=https

2019-11-24T17:47:09.037199+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.51.205.51 - - [24/Nov/2019:17:47:08 +0000] "GET /ajax.php?ajax=server_stats HTTP/1.1" 200 165 "https://ss-leech.herokuapp.com/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
```

SO do you know why this happened?

Update:

Based of @chris question i explain what happened for every wake upping the dyno, as you can see i have installed rapid-leech and after every waking up the dyno it goes to the configuration page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ldM9.png)

and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEb72.png)
to reach the main page of it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGLK.png)

**New Update:**

based of @chris comment i searched the GitHub files and don't find any config.php file accordion the [default.php comments] (github.com/elasa-Sites/heroku-rapidleech/blob/…) like this :

> //Do NOT edit this file //To edit your configuration use web setup
>   (deleting config.php or renaming it to config_old.php and open your
>   rapidleech site)

but don't find config.php file in its Also as i have said at above comments i have this restart problem with another Repo when trying installing WP on Heroku,So i guess the problem is not from here.
you could see the search result files here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJlNq.png)

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "needs to be reconfigured again"? Specifically what configuration are you talking about? How do you perform such configuration in the first place?

Comment: Dear @Chris i have added more explain for **need to reconfigured again** but i don't get where i mentioned to **Ruby and Rail ** ?  **maybe from > What is a dyno in Heroku? The containers used at Heroku are called
> “dynos.” Dynos are isolated, virtualized Linux containers that are
> designed to execute code based on a user-specified command. [link](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Ruby+on+Rails+dyno+heroku&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)** Also i have this problem with other free app when installing and setting my WP Site.

Comment: Your title says "my rails app" and you used the [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag.

Comment: How does your application store its configuration?

Comment: @Chris you are right .

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your applications state (which I assume is what you mean by *configuration* ) is being reset each time the Dyno boots due to the ephemeral filesystem being used, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem for a better explanation. You may also find https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted helpful. Basically, any data stored to the hard drive will not survive when the Dyno reboots (which happens on every deploy, as well as every 24 hours). Instead, you should use cloud storage like Amason AWS S3.

Comment: It looks like [even basic configuration is saved to the filesystem](https://github.com/elasa-Sites/heroku-rapidleech/blob/9d36810a2173b1f2f4fe45dd7d5a79fe28b649fd/configs/default.php#L2-L3). OP will probably need to modify the application (at minimum, will need to modify the configuration file locally and deploy it to Heroku, and quite likely more) or choose another host.

Comment: @Chris i searched the GitHub files and don't find any config.php file accordion the [default.php comments] (https://github.com/elasa-Sites/heroku-rapidleech/blob/9d36810a2173b1f2f4fe45dd7d5a79fe28b649fd/configs/default.php#L2-L3) but don't find config.php file in its Also as i have said at above comments i have this restart problem with another Repo when trying installing WP on Heroku,So i guess the problem is not from here.

Comment: @modern, the application looks like it saves settings in a file called `config.php`. It's not part of the source code. Saving to a file won't work properly on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, i will try to add config.php at the main source at GitHub and hopefully will feedback here the result.

Comment: @modern Apps must be written in a way that makes them amenable to running on Heroku. It's likely this is not the only spot you'll have to make adjustments. See https://blog.heroku.com/twelve-factor-apps.

Comment: @maniacalrobot I have tried to add empty config.php file into config folder of rapid leech file in github repo but now the entire site don't uploaded and get this message:**There's nothing here, yet.** could be seen here:[ss3-leech.herokuapp.com](https://ss3-leech.herokuapp.com/)